# How is self-reference understood in the pragmatist tradition?

Tags: semantics, pragmatism, quine

Gödel and Tarski's works have been especially influential in the pragmatist tradition, but what exactly did their theorems usher in?

What is left of self-reference in the pragmatist tradition?

More specifically, what did Quine think of self-reference in light of his general criticism of reference?

Comment: Just curious, why do you think Tarski and Godel have been influential in the Pragmatist tradition?  When I've seen them referenced by pragmatists it's usually  as important figures playing for the other side.

Comment: @mobileink I can see how that would be misleading. I was thinking about Quine's interpretation of Tarski and his eventual tendency towards deflaitonsim, which seems to me to have a particular role in pragmatism. Overall you are likely right that the two of them have had a greater impact on 'the other side' though.